# Why are my translated Select List values not shown after switching language?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a content type for **Job Openings**, which has many fields and some of them are drop-downs (select lists).

The issue is that when I switch the language (German) everything switches to the currently selected language but the data coming from select field stays in English.

I have been going over the internet and have not found anything. Any suggestions?

**Notes**:

- All the fields are translated in the backend but they just doesn't show up (in German).
- I have simple text_fields too and they are shown translated, but not the select list fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go To **Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » your content type » Manage fields » your select list » Translate**

[image]

Click Translate and Select **Field Settings**. In Field settings update all your options with corresponding translated strings.

[image]

Another option is
Check for any untranslated string here .. **Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface**

Comment: i already have done this with my field

Comment: Check for any untrslated string here .. **Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface**

Comment: thanks alot it did the trick 
i was missing some translations 

i have another issue it would be great if you have a look at it too :

drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/176449/webform-confirmation-message-replacing-my-webform-block-while-using-webform-ajax

Answer (score 3):

After you translated the select list options of your field(s), make sure that you ALSO change the **Format** of that selection list from ***Default*** to ***Default Tanslated***

You can do so via "Manage Display", located at `/admin/structure/types/manage/yourtype/display` (whereas `yourtype` corresponds to your Job Openings content type). Similar to what is explained in [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1101128#comment-6027572) also ...

Comment: Very important indeed. This should be included in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm not sure I understand it entirely. Are you saying that I should further enhance (edit) my answer with that "this"? If so, can you help me on that somehow? Eg via an edit suggestion or so which I'd be happy to review and approve if appropriate, ok?